# how to get maximum value of a field where it has duplicates i am using a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the max value of a field in a table, this is not a primary key. but every transaction posted will duplicate this value in same column. How to get the max value and add 1 to get the next value? I have the following script to extract and add 1 to get the next value. But this gives a wrong value, the table has 10 for two transactions, but the query gives 10.

```
$sql = "select distinct MAX(receipt_id) from gl_transactions_table order by id desc";
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you are trying to make your own AutoIncrement column, which is what it sounds like. Look up auto increment in the MySQL manual and let MySQL do all the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for this ?

```
$sql = "select MAX(receipt_id)+1 as new_id from gl_transactions_table";
```

Comment: this worked for me. SELECT MAX(CAST(receipt_id AS INT)) as max_receipt FROM gl_transactions_table. Thanks for the help..

Comment: Oh, okay ! your `receipt_id` is not a numeric field (is it a VARCHAR ?). Glad you found the issue ! Maybe you should try to convert this column to an INT to prevent further problems.